# get all facebook ids /name of my friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have tried using  the code below and if add old facebook sdk it workd fine but new sdk I get only the friend who is on app.How can I get  the list of all friends in new sdk? .I really appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.:

```
new Request(
            MainActivity.facebook.getSession(),
            "/me/friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    /* handle the result */

                    Toast.makeText(activity, response.toString(), 5).show();

                }
            }
            ).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: You Can´t.

Since v2.0, you can only get the friends who authorized your App too, for privacy reasons. An App should not know about anyone who does not use the App.

If you want the names to tag them, there is [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/taggable_friends). If you want to invite them, use [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2). But check out the docs for their limitations.

Comment: but taggable_friends and invitable_friends is always blank and it saya its only allowed in games.So how do I use it?

Comment: do you want to tag someone or invite someone to a facebook canvas game? because if not, it´s just not possible at all to get all friends.

Comment: also, always try with a user who is admin, developer or tester of the app.

Comment: no I dont have a game I am creating a normal app with facebook login and I would like to send/post on my friends wall .How can I do that ?

Comment: well...you can´t post on your friends wall at all. that possibility was removed a long time ago because it would always be spam. apps should not be posting to friend walls, ESPECIALLY not if the friend does not even use the app.

Comment: I mean notify my friend somehow about the post on my wall.Is that possible ?(like tag i suppose)

Comment: why? what for? that would also be spam. and about tagging, read the docs.

Comment: meaning: don´t notify users who don´t even use your app. people don´t want that, and facebook will surely not like it either. leave non app users alone ;)

Comment: basically how can I overcome facebook messenger from manually selecting but can add list of facebook ids to it or something so that the post/message can be sent to all the users who are still not on app but are there on facebook .I really appreciate your time but this is one such requirement.

Comment: you can´t. period. again, leave non app users alone, they don´t want to get any app notification or message. not every requirement is possible or allowed ;)

Comment: So how would you get users on your app ?? sorry but looking at every angle.

Comment: THAT is very easy: let users invite their friends by sending them a link to the app if they like it. don´t force it. also, that´s beyond the scope of your question, which was only how to get all friends. please add ALL the information in your questions, so we can answer more direct and don´t need to waste a lot of time with comments.

Comment: I tried that but it goes to app section of facebook and users dont even get a notification.AM i doing it right?

Comment: no clue, but as i said: that´s a completely different topic. the question in this thread was only how to get all friends - which is not possible as i have answered. please open a new thread for additional questions, comments are not the right way to talk about something completely different.